Godot4 2d - issue with how polygons and re-useable textures work
I’m trying to create irregular shaped tiles using polygons, and I want to use the same texture for each tile. I have the minimum code below that creates a number of polygons in a row.
extends Node2D

# VARS

# the texture for each polygon
@onready var grass_texture : Texture2D = preload("res://grass_texture.png")

# the shape of the polygon - 64 x 64 square
@onready var polygon_corners : PackedVector2Array = [
    Vector2(0, 0),
    Vector2(64, 0),
    Vector2(64, 64),
    Vector2(0, 64),
]

# the number of polygons in a row
@onready var number_of_polygons : int = 3

# the spacing between the top-left corner of each polygon
@onready var polygon_spacing : Vector2 = Vector2(128, 0)


# FUNCS
func _ready():
    
    # for each polygon
    for polygon_number in number_of_polygons:
        
        # create a variable to hold the updated coordinates for each corner
        var corner_coordinates : PackedVector2Array
        
        # for each corner, take the original position, and create world coordinates based on which polygon it is
        for corner in polygon_corners:
            var corner_coordinate : Vector2 = corner + (polygon_spacing * polygon_number)
            corner_coordinates.append(corner_coordinate) # add coordinates to the holding variable
        
        # now we have the coordinates, create a polygon
        var new_polygon = Polygon2D.new()
        
        # add the coordinates data, the texture, and add it to the tree
        new_polygon.polygon = corner_coordinates
        new_polygon.texture = grass_texture
        add_child(new_polygon)

test texture
test result
The texture for the first polygon is displayed properly, but for the remaining polygon, only a plain green texture is shown. I suspect the issue might be something to do with either UVs (which I’ve left empty), or how I’ve imported the texture resource.
I've tried:
Just polygons + textures
Setting polygon as a scene and instantiating
duplicating the texture in both cases
making texture resource unique
Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong? I’ve linked below the texture I’m using, plus the test result. In each case listed above, the outcome is the same
